# Getting R error "replacement has x rows, data has y" when creating a new boolean column in dataframe based on matches with a different dataframe

Tags: r

I have the following two dataframes (simplified for question):

**nsPre** (smaller dataframe):

```
gene_id_name
ENSG00000005020|SKAP2
ENSG00000017260|ATP2C1
ENSG00000027869|SH2D2A
ENSG00000039319|ZFYVE16
.
.
.
```

**g0** (larger dataframe):

```
gene_id_name            pLI       g_eGenes_general
ENSG00000005020|SKAP2   0.00823   0
ENSG00000039319|ZFYVE16 0.12104   0
ENSG00000087884|AAMDC   0.13539   1
ENSG00000027869|SH2D2A  0.002489  1
ENSG00000124608|AARS2   0.32500   0
.
.
.
```

What I'm trying to do is create a new column in `g0` called `g_eGenes_nsPre` that assigns a value of `1` whenever the `gene_id_name` values match, and a value of `0` when they don't, like below:

**Desired outcome:**

```
gene_id_name            pLI      g_eGenes_general   g_eGenes_nsPre
ENSG00000005020|SKAP2   0.00823  0                  1
ENSG00000039319|ZFYVE16 0.12104  0                  1
ENSG00000087884|AAMDC   0.13539  1                  0
ENSG00000027869|SH2D2A  0.002489 1                  1
ENSG00000124608|AARS2   0.32500  0                  0
```

**Current attempt:**

```
df = g0
df <- na.omit(df)    
df$g_eGenes_nsPre <- ifelse(nsPre$gene_id_name %in% g0$gene_id_name, 1, 0)
df$g_eGenes_nsPost <- ifelse(nsPost$gene_id_name %in% g0$gene_id_name, 1, 0)
```

**Error when running above code:**

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, g_eGenes_nsPre, value = c(1, 1, 1,  : 
  replacement has 2039 rows, data has 15430
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R

```
transform(g0, g_eGenes_nsPre = apply(g0, 1, function(x)
    as.integer(x["gene_id_name"] %in% nsPre$gene_id_name)))
#             gene_id_name      pLI g_eGenes_general g_eGenes_nsPre
#1   ENSG00000005020|SKAP2 0.008230                0              1
#2 ENSG00000039319|ZFYVE16 0.121040                0              1
#3   ENSG00000087884|AAMDC 0.135390                1              0
#4  ENSG00000027869|SH2D2A 0.002489                1              1
#5   ENSG00000124608|AARS2 0.325000                0              0
```

Instrad of `as.integer` you can also use the unary `+` operator.

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
g0 %>%
    mutate(g_eGenes_nsPre = +(gene_id_name %in% nsPre$gene_id_name))
#             gene_id_name      pLI g_eGenes_general g_eGenes_nsPre
#1   ENSG00000005020|SKAP2 0.008230                0              1
#2 ENSG00000039319|ZFYVE16 0.121040                0              1
#3   ENSG00000087884|AAMDC 0.135390                1              0
#4  ENSG00000027869|SH2D2A 0.002489                1              1
#5   ENSG00000124608|AARS2 0.325000                0              0
```

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(g0)[, g_eGenes_nsPre := +(gene_id_name %in% nsPre$gene_id_name)]
```

---

### Sample data

```
nsPre <- read.table(text =
    "gene_id_name
ENSG00000005020|SKAP2
ENSG00000017260|ATP2C1
ENSG00000027869|SH2D2A
ENSG00000039319|ZFYVE16", header = T)

g0 <- read.table(text =
    "gene_id_name            pLI       g_eGenes_general
ENSG00000005020|SKAP2   0.00823   0
ENSG00000039319|ZFYVE16 0.12104   0
ENSG00000087884|AAMDC   0.13539   1
ENSG00000027869|SH2D2A  0.002489  1
ENSG00000124608|AARS2   0.32500   0", header = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple oneliner using `data.table`: first make `g_eGenes_nsPre` column with all zeroes, then change values to ones for rows which `gene_id_names` are in the other data.frame.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(g0); setDT(nsPre)
g0[,g_eGenes_nsPre:=0][gene_id_name%in%nsPre$gene_id_name,g_eGenes_nsPre:=1]
```